# How to config automatic proxy from DHCP in windows server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, proxy, dhcp, transparent-proxy, proxy.pac

I am running squid proxy, and currently my users are being configured directly to the squid server. I am trying to setup a proxy.pac to simplify the process.

The proxy.pac working fine in the network by configuring the configuration URL, but we need to make the user find out proxy.pac automatically so that there won't be any further necessary config for the end user.

How can I config the DHCP server to supply proxy(proxy.pac) automatically to my users?

I am running DHCP on windows server 2003.
Proxy on squid.
No active directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick the proxy.pac on some sort of HTTP server that the client systems can access.

Add Option 252 to your DHCP config with the location of the file; Microsoft has the specific steps outlined [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb794881.aspx) (using proxy.pac instead of wpad.dat, of course).